# Order Shipment email template in get Base Cost of Iteams..How to Get base Cost in magento1?

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, shipment

[image]Order Shipment email template in get BaseCost of Iteams..How to Get base Cost??
Use this code but not getting Base cost..

```
$shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->loadByIncrementId($shipid);
$itemsCollection = $shipment->getItemsCollection();
foreach($itemsCollection as $item)
{
    $baseCost= $item->getBaseCost();
}
```

Same as need to set Email Template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per as, default magento `base_cost` is **not a field of** `sales_flat_shipment_item`.

So, you could not get it `base_cost` from `$item->getBaseCost();`

As per as, my concept ,`base_cost` is an attribute of product.So if want to get it ***value then you need to call product model*** (`Mage::getModel('catalog/product')`).

You can get product from `$item->getProductId()`,So using *product id,you can get this field value.*

```
$_resource = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->getResource();
$base_cost = $_resource->getAttributeRawValue($item->getProductId(),  'base_cost', Mage::app()->getStore());
```

**at $item should be `$_item`  if `\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\email\order\items‌​\shipment\default.phtml`**

**Or by full load by product model:**

```
         $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->setStoreId($_item->getOrderItem()->getOrder()->getStoreId())
                ->load($_item->getProductId());

            if($product->getId()) {
echo $product->getBaseCost();
}
```

Comment: Yes Right but i try $item->getProductId()->getBaseCost(); but empty result found.

Comment: i try above code in \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\email\order\items\shipment

Comment: Default.phtml i use your code but not getting result.

Comment: $item should be $_item

Comment: great..works fine.